# Facebook tab page load app doesn't pass parameter

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an app in a facebook page tab that show some informations and this information must change for every user (ID_USER). I don't know how to load the correct data in the facebook app tab page. My app is a Django app. I've done this step:

1) create an app in my developers account (a page tab application) with this url https://www.exemple.com/ID_USER.

2) load the url https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=MY_APP_ID&redirect_uri=www.exemple.com/ID_USER

3) Select in the window the page to install the app

4) I go to the page and I found the app.

The problem is that the app is only for a user and I would like to load the right data for every facebook page the app is installed.

I've read about signed_request and app_data but I don't understand how to set app_data. Canyou help me please?

*** EDIT ***

The problem seems to be the django internationalization redirect from

- https://www.example.com/ID_USER
  to
- https://www.example.com/en/ID_USER

in my network console I see

302 https://www.example.com/ID_USER (with 'signed_request')
200 https://www.example.com/en/ID_USER (without 'signed_request')

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I assume you don’t mean the user id, but the _page id_? That one you can get from the `signed_request` that gets POSTed to your app on initial load into the iframe.

Comment: ID_USER is a my django app parameter and is necessary for load the data of that specific user. I've try to get request.POST.get('signed_request') in the view but request.POST is null.

Comment: @CBroe the problem is that I don't get signed_request in my request.POST. Could be a redirect problem?

Comment: Of course you can not redirect – the browser follows that by issuing a GET request, and that means you lose all POST data. You need to process the POST data before any redirect happens.